# How can I troubleshoot Bluetooth not working on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS?

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, dongle

On Windows 10, the dongle I am using is detected and the operating system can detect any Bluetooth device sending a signal. On Ubuntu, however, I can't get it to work. I believe there is not a working repo, or hardware support, or outdated driver configs.

What happens is an endless search for devices with nothing being detected.

Here is a screenshot showing the Bluetooth interface searching for devices:

[image: screenshot showing the bluetooth interface searching for devices]

Does anyone know if there is a repository is missing from 20.04.3 LTS that is preventing Bluetooth devices from connecting? How do I get Bluetooth working in 20.04.3 LTS?

Comment: What is the make/model of the bluetooth dongle you are using? As far as the devices you are trying to connect, what are the model numbers of these devices?  Your question indicates that you've already tried a few things to get this working.  Can you edit your question with the details of those attempts?  Sometimes when people troubleshoot, they inadvertently do something early on in their attempts that end up preventing things from working even if the correct steps are taken later.  It would be best if you would describe the context/history around your attempts to get it working.

Comment: @Nmath I'm using a generic bluetooth v5.0 dongle; the only thing I have attempted so far was installing blueman, which yielded no results; I removed it already;
this to me, looks at lot like when Debian started removing support for a couple of wifi dongles, making compatibility issues with older models;

edit: I am trying to pair Mi wireless earbuds, they pair fine on ClayxOS (android), so I am almost certain that someone deleted a repo from Debian for whatever reason, problem gets pulled into Ubuntu. I am not certain but I suspect that there is something missing

Comment: Somewhere in the technical specifications there will be a particular chipset being used even if it's a "generic" manufacturer.  You can either provide to us the make and model of your device and we can try to look it up for you, or you can research the make model and find out what chipset the dongle has and let us know. I've not heard of hardware support for Wi-Fi or Bluetooth components being removed in Debian or Ubuntu. Your theory of "repos missing" isn't consistent with how repos work in relation to hardware, but in any case, we need to know the chipset model to troubleshoot further.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add the relevant line from the `lsusb` command. That will identify the chipset, the only info that matters.